# adding a timestamp in hh:mm timestamp in googlescript

Tags: google-apps-script, time, timestamp

Does anyone know how to add a timestamp into one cell when the script runs and be in hh:mm format.

the nearest I can get is

```
function RefreshORM(){

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()

 ss.getSheetByName('ORM').getRange('D17').clear({contentsOnly: true})
 ss.getSheetByName('ORM').getRange('M21:M120').clear({contentsOnly: true})
 ss.getSheetByName('ORM').getRange('D17').setValue(new Date())
```

}

but it comes in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm format and throws off the formulas.

Answer (score 1):

You can format the Date object returned by `new Date()` using the `Utilities.formatDate(Date,Timezone,Format)` function, however you need to be confident of the correct timezone. Assuming you do you work in one timezone, this is straightforward.

```
//assuming your timezone is 'EST'

ss.getSheetByName('ORM').getRange('D17').setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),'EST','HH:mm'));
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)

Comment: Thats perfect thank you, I was looking at them pieces but I couldn't get it to function correctly.